# Custom Checkbox with multiple images

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to have an image instead of a text box. Googling I found this site: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ and I really like how it looks. But since the check boxes I need are to 'share also' in facebook and twiter I need two different images on the checkboxes. I could do that by modifying first the css:

```
.checkboxfb {
width: 23px; height: 23px; padding: 0 5px 0 0;
background: url(images/files/ico_facebook_mult_sml2.png) no-repeat;
display: block; clear: left; float: left;}

.checkboxtw {
width: 23px; height: 22px; padding: 0 5px 0 0;
background: url(images/files/twitter_logo_mult_sml.png) no-repeat;
display: block; clear: left; float: left;}
```

I differentiated the classes between one another in the html:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
<input type="checkbox" name="fb" class="styledfb" />FB <br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="tw" class="styledtw" />TW </form>
```

And duplicating the script, FBcheckbox.js:

```
document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled**fb** { display: none; } select.styled**fb** { position: relative; width: ' + selectWidth + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

var Custom = {
inita: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if((inputs[a].type == "checkbox" || inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className == "styledfb") {
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
            span[a].className = inputs[a].type + "**fb**";
```

of course, the other js file will have 'tw' instead of 'fb' and it is called TWcheckbox.js.
(you can see the whole js here: http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/js/checkbox/FBcheckbox.js and http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/js/checkbox/TWcheckbox.js ).

In the header I am calling both files:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/checkbox/FBcheckbox.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/checkbox/TWcheckbox.js"></script>
> ```

Now the funny thing is that only one of them works at a time. Whichever is second when calling them in the header. The test file is http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/test1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your script files are assigning the value of your `Custom` variable. When the second of the two files is loaded, it overwrites the previous assignment to `Custom`. Even though you have separate `inita` and `initb` functions, the whole of the `Custom` object is overwritten when the second JS file is loaded.

So, if FBcheckbox.js loads first, `inita` is defined within the object, but when TWcheckbox.js loads and reassigns the content of `Custom` rather than adding to it, `inita` no longer exists when the page load event fires because TWcheckbox.js's version of `Custom` doesn't include `inita`.

Since it seems like the only functions that differ within the `Custom` object in your JS files are `inita` and `initb`, I would recommend assigning them together in on file. Something like:

```
var Custom = {
  inita: function() {
    // ...your code here...
  },
  initb: function() {
    // ...your code here...
  },
  pushed: function() {
    // ...your code here...
  },
  // etc...
};
```

If you want to keep them separated, you could add code that checks for the existence of the object prior to its assignment and if the object exists, add to it rather than re-assign the whole thing. However, I think combining the two as above will reduce duplication across your code.

```
if (typeof(Custom)!="undefined" && !Custom.inita) {
  Custom.inita = function() { /* ...your code here... */ }
} else if (typeof(Custom)=="undefined") {
  var Custom = {
    // ...your code here...
  };
};
```

Assigning both init functions using `window.onload` presents the same problem. The JS file loaded most recently will overwrite the previously assigned window.onload value rather than add to it. To assign more than one function to fire onload of the page, you should use syntax like the following:

In FBcheckbox.js:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load",Customa.inita,false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload",Customa.inita);
}
```

In TWcheckbox.js:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load",Customb.initb,false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload",Customb.initb);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. But I still have some troubles: what would be the syntax for the 'window.onload = Custom.init;' so it fires both inita and initb?

Comment: I am experimenting to have Customa and Customb as variables and same outcome: just the second one shows up!

Comment: Hey @cbarg, sorry I missed that portion intially. Assigning window.onload twice has the same problem - the window.onload assignment most recently run will overwrite the previous value. The way around it would be to use syntax like the following: `if (window.addEventListener) { window.addEventListener("load",Customa.inita,false); } else if (window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent("onload",Customa.inita); }` - for the second JS file, you'd switch `Customa.inita` to `Customb.initb`.

Comment: I've updated the original answer to include more information on the window.onload issue in a cleaner format.